# My Request.Files in action side is always null when uploading file by ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to upload an image by ajax mode in MVC .I used this method everything is ok in Js code it gets the formdata and the ajax request is sent to the controller correctly but in my controler i get Request.File["myfile"] always null ... i seached everywhere for the solution but didn't find please help me thats so emergency ... Thank's all
here is my js codes :

```js
  function UploadImage() {
   var data = new FormData();
   var files = $("#myfile").get(0).files;
   if (files.length > 0) {
    data.append("MyImages", files[0]);
   }

  $.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SaveFile","Home")",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
     //code after success
     console.log(response);
     alert(response);
    },
    error: function (er) {
     alert(er);
    }

   });
  }
 
Html:
```

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>upload</title>
 <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
 <div class="container">
  <div>
   file:<input type="file" id="myfile" style="display: block"/>
   <br />
   <input type="button" value="save" id="btnUpload" onclick="UploadImage()"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and My Action:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveFile()
    {
        var uniqueName = "";
        if (Request.Files["myfile"] != null)
        {
            var file = Request.Files["myfile"];
            if (file.FileName != "")
            {
                var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                uniqueName = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;

                var rootPath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");

                var fileSavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, uniqueName);
                file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
            }
        }

        return Json(new
        {
            success=false,
            name=uniqueName
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: you have to pass formdata replace `data: {}` with `data: data,`

Comment: Note also you can simply give your file input a `name` attribute (say `name="file"`) and use `var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));` and remove the the unnecessary `enctype: 'multipart/form-data',` and you POST method an be `public JsonResult SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)

Comment: With your current code, eve when you do actually send your data, yor referring to a non existent property - you named it `"MyImages"`, not `"myfile"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/upload-files-through-jquery-ajax-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) that is very similar to your code

change this

```
data: {}
```

by this

```
data: data
```

Sample code VIEW

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload1" />  
<input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload Files" />  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#btnUpload').click(function () {  

        // Checking whether FormData is available in browser  
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {  

            var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);  
            var files = fileUpload.files;  

            // Create FormData object  
            var fileData = new FormData();  

            // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object  
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
                fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);  
            }  

            // Adding one more key to FormData object  
            fileData.append('username', ‘Manas’);  

            $.ajax({  
                url: '/Home/UploadFiles',  
                type: "POST",  
                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
                processData: false, // Not to process data  
                data: fileData,  
                success: function (result) {  
                    alert(result);  
                },  
                error: function (err) {  
                    alert(err.statusText);  
                }  
            });  
        } else {  
            alert("FormData is not supported.");  
        }  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

Sample Code CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult UploadFiles()  
{  
// Checking no of files injected in Request object  
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            //  Get all files from Request object  
            HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;  
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)  
            {  
                //string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/";  
                //string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);  

                HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];  
                string fname;  

                // Checking for Internet Explorer  
                if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")  
                {  
                    string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });  
                    fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    fname = file.FileName;  
                }  

                // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
                fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), fname);  
                file.SaveAs(fname);  
            }  
            // Returns message that successfully uploaded  
            return Json("File Uploaded Successfully!");  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            return Json("Error occurred. Error details: " + ex.Message);  
        }  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return Json("No files selected.");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you my friend that was really helpful

Comment: @HosseinGholizadeh, please avoid saying thanks in stackoverflow (see rules here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please accept this anser or vote +1 on it if it helped you